# Split is not a function?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, split

I have this code I was testing with:

```
var test:String="Hello there; im zane"
var parts:Array=test.split(";");
trace(parts)
trace(parts[0])
var randomnum:Number=0; 
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, code)
function code(c:Event):void{
    if(parts[randomnum] != undefined && parts[randomnum] != null){
        parts[randomnum]=parts[randomnum].split(" "); 
        randomnum+=1
        trace(parts[randomnum])
        }
    else{
        randomnum=0
        }
}
```

And there is an error with this `parts[randomnum]=parts[randomnum].split(" ");`. Flash says that split is not a function (

TypeError: Error #1006: split is not a function.
    at Untitled_fla::MainTimeline/code()

)

Earlier in this project, I used the split function with a different part of the variable, and I also tried `parts[0]=parts[0].split(" ")` out of the event and it worked fine.

What I'm trying to find out is, why does a split command not work in this scenario? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `trace(parts[randomnum])` and make sure it's a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also tried `parts[0]=parts[0].split(" ")` out of the event and it worked fine.

Even outside of the event, this line doesn't make much sense, because it assigns the return value of `split()` to the same variable that the method was invoked on. As the `ENTER_FRAME` is repeatedly executed, this **fails on the second time it happens, because `split()` returns an `Array` which has no such method itself**, which is what the error is basically saying.

Comment: I made it so that when it finishes it will not repeat. That worked